# Passing a static variable with multiple different threads running - TestNG

Tags: java, multithreading, static, testng, appium

I am using TestNG in order to run automated mobile tests in parallel using Appium.

I have a method in one class that initiates an AppiumDriver object.

I call this method from my TestNG class in order for each thread to create it's own instance of the driver. Trouble is, because it's a static variable, when each of the threads tries to access the driver from **another class** via a static method:

There is always conflicts, as each thread only has access to a single implementation of the AppiumDriver object.

I understand i can bypass this by having all this code within a single class that the TestNG XML file communicates with, but this is messy and i'd prefer to have separate classes for different parts of functionality.

For example, i have a custom TestNG listener that i would like to print driver details each thread is using after each test method is run. With the following method:

However, this always prints the last running thread's driver.

How might i go about ensuring the returned driver the from the `method is consistent to the driver that was created in the` method?

Comment: I'm not sure why it's static, but consider a `Map<Configuration, AppiumDriver<MobileElement>> drivers`, where `Configuration` contains `platform`, `udid`, etc.  Pass a `confiugration` to the `getDriver(Configuration c)` to get the previously set up driver out of the map.

Comment: While this helps with getting the driver details for each thread, it still leads to the case where the threads are using the incorrect driver during execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running your test in parallel, then we need to use the non static method to avoid the conflicts. All the above methods needs to be changed as non static.

You need to modify your listener class as below and it will give the driver details correctly. We need to get the current class instance from the `ITestResult`

**Listener Code:**

```
public class ResultsListener implements ISuiteListener, IInvokedMethodListener {

    @Override
    public void afterInvocation(IInvokedMethod method, ITestResult testResult) {

        Object currentClass=testResult.getInstance();
        WebDriver driver = ((AppiumSetUp) currentClass).getDriver();
        System.out.println("Driver details:  " + driver);
     }
}
```

**Edit:**

You can extends the AppiumSetUp class in all required class(atleast in @BeforeTest method class).So, that you can directly access the setup method as below. For the example purpose, I have added the class name as `BeforeTestSetup`

```
   public class BeforeTestSetup extends AppiumSetUp{


    @BeforeTest(alwaysRun = true)
    @Parameters({"platform", "udid", "chromeDriverPort", "chromeDriverPath", "deviceName"}) 
    public void setUp(String platform, String udid, String chromeDriverPort, @Optional String chromeDriverPath, String deviceName) throws Exception { 

        driver = setUp(platform, udid, chromeDriverPort, deviceName); 
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure a i follow this. You are casting a Setup object? Would this be AppiumSetUp in my case?

Comment: It is an AppiumSetUp in your case. I have updated the answer

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that i need the setUp method to remain static, as it's called from my TestNg class to create an AppiumDriver

Comment: Like so 
@BeforeTest(alwaysRun = true)
    @Parameters({"platform", "udid", "chromeDriverPort", "chromeDriverPath", "deviceName"})
    public void setUp(String platform, String udid, String chromeDriverPort, @Optional String chromeDriverPath, String deviceName) throws Exception {
     driver = AppiumSetUp(platform, udid, chromeDriverPort, deviceName);
    }

Comment: I have edited the answer and added the @BeforeTest method

Comment: Thanks for the help. Are there any further examples of this approach that i could find online?

Comment: Your above answer gives an error due to the extended setUp method in BeforeTestSetup class differs from the setUp method in the superclass.